# What is the correct way to create new raid5 in Linux?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm

I added some new disks, and tried to create new array, using:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md/2 --level=5 -x 0 --raid-devices=4/dev/sd{a,b,c,g}2
```

It creates the array, but after reboot - it's gone. What should I do to keep it visible?

Also - I read [about spare disks](http://marc.info/?l=linux-raid&m=112044009718483&w=2), and so when I see that the raid was created, and it shows (in /proc/mdstat):

```
md2 : active (auto-read-only) raid5 sdg2[4](S) sdc2[2] sdb2[1] sda2[0]
```

I understand that sdg2 is treated as spare. But why isn't it automatically rebuilding/syncing the data?

Comment: `What should I do to keep it visible` - fix your mdadm.conf file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add all the arrays found on the system to mdadm.conf so it will be started at each boot:

```
mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Alternatively, you can run `mdadm --examine --scan` and add the arrays you want manually in *mdadm.conf*.

Comment: and update-initramfs -u to ensure you get the array correctly loading after reboot!

Answer (score 1):

This issue could also arise because of device renaming, Try removing the /dev devices from the ARRAY specification and only use the UUID.